# How to hide commands typed in a Linux shell?

Tags: shell, command-line

Is there a way to hide what I'm typing in a shell, so the terminal doesn't echo my keystrokes, while still keeping the output of the command?

For example, if I run `ip addr show`, the only thing on the screen should be the output from that command -- not the "ip addr show" that I typed.

Comment: Hi. Can you be bit more specific about, `content`?

Comment: Do you mean hiding the standard input like when typing the password on `login`? Are you using `bash`? Provide some more information please.

Comment: content means commands, for example if i type an command "ip addr show" it must be not visible in the bash terminal what i am typing . But it can i view the output of it

Comment: That's a weird requirement. What are you trying to achieve? Note that with typical shells, the command will also be entered in the history and saved to disk.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want to disable echo of the commands you type, try this:

```
stty -echo
```

You can re-enable echo using this command:

```
stty echo
```

Note that the output of commands will show up in a somewhat different way, see this example session:

```
$ pwd
/tmp
$ stty -echo
$ /tmp
```

This resulted from typing `pwd`, return, `stty -echo`, return, `pwd`, return.

Comment: Note that this may or may not work depending on your shell, and perhaps on what oddities you put in your prompt. Also the setting applies to everything in that terminal; if you run a full-screen command it's likely to reset to `stty +echo`.